# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter - Write Object with List as fields to CSV file

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have the following Pojo classes:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    List<Interest> interests;
}

public class Interest {
    String name;
    Date createdAt;
}
```

I have the following CSV file with the header in place:

```
NAME,AGE,INTEREST_1,INTEREST_2,INTEREST_3,INTERESTS_ADDITIONAL
```

Is it possible to have a FlatFileItemWriter that would write into the csv file based on that header?

The first 3 interests in the list of interests of each student will go into the 3rd, 4th and 5th columns and if there are more than 3 in the list just add their names into the 6th column.

Up until now I always used a FlatFileItemWriter similar to this:

```
public FlatFileItemWriter<Student> writer() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Student> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(outputResource);
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Student>() {
      {
          setDelimiter(",");
          setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Student>() {
              {
                  setNames(new String[] { "name", "age", "interest" });
              }
          });
      }
    });
    return writer;
}
```

But this won't work for list of interest.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just write your own custom `LineAggregator` to do that, or use an `ItemProcessor` to transform the `Student` and `Interest` into another java class that matches the CVS you want to write, then use a regular `FlatFileItemWriter` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `FieldExtactor` to extract fields as needed. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Student> itemWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Student> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(outputResource);
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Student>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(new FieldExtractor<Student>() {
                @Override
                public Object[] extract(Student student) {
                    List<Object> fields = new ArrayList<>();
                    fields.add(student.getName());
                    fields.add(student.getAge());
                    // add interests as needed to the list
                    return fields.toArray();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a custom FieldExtractor approach helped.